# Rails 3 - find_all_by_car_id and nil object

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, find

I am getting this error:
[code]
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
[/code]

In controller:

```
@optionals = Car.find_all_by_car_id(1)
```

In view:

```
<% @optionals.each do |c| %>
  <div><%= c.type %></div>
<% end %>
```

In the table Car is one row... so I don't understand, how is possible to getting this error message... I tried to search on google, but unfortunately I still don't know how to fix this error...

So I'll glad for each help!

EDIT: **car_id** in table **Cars** have the value **1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a line in the template like so:

`<%= @optionals.inspect %>` and make sure it's not nil.

If it is, check the log to make sure the action that you're calling matches the template you're looking at